# How to arrange google chrome developer tools options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How can I arrange where tool options are placed, like I illustrate in the screenshot:
[image]

I don't have any idea how I located this panel on the top but it's annoying. The default view: 
[image: default view]

Or maybe just reset view settings..

Answer (score 0):

The second screenshot is from an older version of Chrome, the first screenshot is from the newer version with a new layout and as far as I know you can't alter this new layout.